# Push certain project files to different repo?

Tags: java, git, gradle

I wish to push certain files (executable JARs from the project) to different repo.

Can I do this with just Git?

Can I do this with Git + Gradle?

Comment: Git doesn't push files, it pushes commits.  That being said, do you have a commit or commits which you want to push?

Comment: I just want to have certain files in separate repo. I agree to have local repo first.

Comment: I'm confused.  What is stopping you from adding the JARs to a branch in that repo, committing, and then pushing?  This is how it is typically done, unless you have a reason to do otherwise.

Comment: A binary repository is a better fit for storing and sharing JARs (even if they are executable but that's implementation detail) than a Git repository.

Comment: Having big files in the repo make it very slow.. Better to keep binaries above 20MB in some kind of shared path instead of having it in repo.

Comment: Are you interested in maintaining the version history for that one file you want to push?